# Android - block swipe-to-refresh action while a refresh is in progress

Tags: android, android-cardview, pull-to-refresh, swiperefreshlayout, swipe-gesture

I need help with a bug. 
I have been looking for the solution to this bug for three days, I explain the situation: I want to display some cards, let's assume they are 10, and I also implement a counter for them. They are generated, but once I use the refresh action (several times in a very short time) the number of cards is doubled (counter = 20, displays a copy of each card).

I'm trying to implement the swipe-to-refresh (pull-to-refresh) function of android, I'm using it with a recyclerview that contains cards, everything works correctly except for the fact that when I start the refresh action, then during a refresh, it is not disabled refresh function and can be updated more than once (depending on the speed even 3 times) and the number of cards and the respective counter is doubled (or tripled). 
I tried to use the following function:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setEnabled(false);
```

This is the code I am using:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout1 = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setEnabled(false);
            refreshContent();
            mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });
```

and this is the refresh function:

```
/*** refresher action ***/
private void refreshContent(){
    cardList.clear();    // clear the card list
    count = 0;           // reset the counter
    // build cards and counter
    mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);
}
```

i'm try this too, but nothing:

```
/*** refresher action ***/
private void refreshContent(){
    cardList.clear();    // clear the card list
    count = 0;           // reset the counter
    mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setEnabled(false);      //*
    // build cards and set counter
    mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);   
    mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setEnabled(true);       //*
}
```

Since if I wait for the refresh (animation) action to work properly, I need something that disables the refresh action for the duration of the previous refresh, so I do not run into this bug. Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I'm try this too, but nothing:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            if (control){
                control = false;    // boolean 
                refreshContent();
                control = true;
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why are you integrating a swipeRefresh/loading if you're just loading a synchronous method? or your card data list is from an API call?

Comment: I need to read data from database, isn't static data.

Comment: Ok, I've added an answer, I've included my code on how I handle swipe refresh layout on all of my projects with it. (Actually almost allof my projects has swipe refresh). You just need to call post() on swipe refresh then from there, call the setRefreshing() method of swipeRefreshLayout

Comment: Have you figured out how to solve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

You can do simple fix using `boolean isLoading` flag and callback.

```
void refresh() {
    if(!isLoading) {
        isLoading = true;
        loadYourData(() -> {
            isLoading = false;
        })
    }
}
```

Now when user activate refresh during refreshing, there is nothing happens.
Don't forget to add some error callback as well (if needed).

Comment: I'm try this too in onRefresh() method, but doesn't work.

Comment: @mixx you need to add callback for your data loading (if it is async)
`if (control) {
    control = false;
    refreshContent(() -> {
        control = true;
    }
);`

Answer (score 0):

I've been using this method for years:

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshContent();
        }
    });
```

And your `refreshContent()` method:

```
private void refreshContent() {
   mSwipeRefreshLayout1.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(true);
            }
        });

  //call async method to load data....
}
```

And on your callback after you receive the data:

```
private void callback() {
    mSwipeRefreshLayout1.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mSwipeRefreshLayout1.setRefreshing(false);
            }
        });

   //clear the view and load it again
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Here "//clear the view and load it again" i need to clear var (cardList.clear(); count = 0;) and load data too as in "//call async method to load data...."? and where i must call callback method?

Comment: What are you using when you're loading the data? asynctask? volley? retrofit? all of them has a callback method in which it gives you back the data, that's the callback I'm talking about here.

Comment: "Clear the view and load it again" yes, it means your: cardList.clear(); count = 0;

Comment: I'm using firebase db tool , have only methods as void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) ( to read data and create cards) and void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) (for db error), all two in a query on db.

Comment: That's the callback im talking about.